# How do I get first name and last name as whole name in a MYSQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to be able to do something like this

```
SELECT `first_name` + " " + `last_name` as `whole_name` FROM `users`
```

So basically I get one column back `whole_name` which is `first_name` and `last_name` concatenated together with a   (space).

How do I do that in SQL, or more specifically, MySQL ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", `first_name`, `last_name`) AS `whole_name` FROM `users`
```

Comment: +1: CONCAT would work just fine too: `CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS whole_name`

Comment: CONCAT_WS is safe when you have fields with a NULL (ex: middle name).
CONCAT will return NULL if any of the concatenated field is a null

Answer (score 6):

You can use a query to get the same:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName , ' ' , MiddleName , ' ' , Lastname) AS Name FROM TableName;
```

Note: This query return if all columns have some value if anyone is null or empty then it will return null for all, means Name will return "NULL"

To avoid above we can use the `IsNull` keyword to get the same.

```
SELECT Concat(Ifnull(FirstName,' ') ,' ', Ifnull(MiddleName,' '),' ', Ifnull(Lastname,' ')) FROM TableName;
```

If anyone containing null value the ' ' (space) will add with next value.

Comment: CONCAT_WS is easier (see @Borealid's answer) but IfNull(field, '') is handy to remember for fixing NULLs in individual fields.

Answer (score 4):

When you have three columns : first_name, last_name, mid_name:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN mid_name IS NULL OR TRIM(mid_name) ='' THEN
        CONCAT_WS( " ", first_name, last_name ) 
    ELSE 
        CONCAT_WS( " ", first_name, mid_name, last_name ) 
    END 
FROM USER;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rtrim(lastname)+','+rtrim(firstname) as [Person Name]
from Table
```

the result will show lastname,firstname as one column header !